# Regex not working in PHP same as with C#

Tags: php, regex

For some reason the following regex which does work in .NET is not working in PHP:

```
// Line breaks not in real expression, just for clarity here to show sub-expressions:
$pattern = <<<REGEX
  "(\\"|[^"])*"
|
  '(\\'|[^'])*'
|
  [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\-\d]*
|
  [\-\+]?\d+(\.\d+)?
|
  [=<>!][=]
|
  [?:,()*\/\-\+!]
|
  \|\|?
|
\&\&?
REGEX;
```

Actual expression for testing:

```
$pattern = '/"(\\\"|[^"])*"|\'(\\\'|[^\'])*\'|[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\-\d]*|[\-\+]?\d+(\.\d+)?|[=<>!][=]|[?:,()*\/\-\+!]|\|\|?|\&\&?/';

$expr = <<<EXPR
something ? '<a href="example.com">', title, '</a>' : title
EXPR;

preg_match_all($pattern, $expr, $tokens);
```

**Expected Output for `$tokens[0]`**

```
0: something
1: ?
2: '<a href="something.com">'       // Please note that ' are part of token!
3: ,
4: title
5: ,
6: '</a>'
7: :
8: title
```

**Actual Output for `$tokens[0]`**

```
0: something
1: ?
2: a
3: href
4: something
5: com
```

For some reason most of the input is missing and the literal has been ignored. This works in .NET but for some reason is not working in PHP.

Comment: Just a thought: If you are trying to extract parts of your DOM, using something like http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php can make your life a lot easier when trying to extract information.

Comment: @afuzzyllama it isn't for analysing markup, the markup is just a string literal within my own simple expression language. It is for data binding and contains very basic syntax. My evaluator works fine when tokens are hard coded, but the regex isn't breaking the input expression down properly.

Comment: @afuzzyllama updated question with comment. the apostrophes ' are actually part of the required string token.

Comment: copy&paste -> `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ']'` please double-check the example script.

Comment: @VolkerK I am not getting that error, but I have put the exact version that I am using beneath the original sample.

Comment: You say: _"// Line breaks not in real expression..."_ OK, what is the "real" expression. You need to post the _exact code_ you are using which doesn't work. (When working with regex, the devil is in the details!) e.g. For starters, your pattern is missing its required regex delimiters.

Comment: @ridgerunner the real expression is below the line-broken version

Comment: Changed $pattern from heredoc to regular escaped as it appears to work slightly better, but still not working as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to escape the regex backslash metacharacters. Also, it is best to write out complex regexes in free-spacing mode with lots of comments. Here is the PHP code you need:

```php
<?php
$pattern = '%
      "(\\\\"|[^"])*"          # Either... a double quoted string,
    |                          # or...
      \'(\\\\\'|[^\'])*\'      # a single quoted string,
    |                          # or...
      [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\-\d]*  # an identifier.
    |                          # or...
      [\-\+]?\d+(\.\d+)?       # a number
    |                          # or...
      [=<>!][=]                # a comparison operator,
    |                          # or...
      [?:,()*\/\-\+!]          # a single char 
    |                          # or...
      \|\|?                    # a logical or numerical OR
    |                          # or...
    \&\&?                      # a logical or numerical AND
    %ix';

$expr = <<<EXPR
something ? '<a href="example.com">', title, '</a>' : title
EXPR;

$a = preg_match_all($pattern, $expr, $tokens);
print_r($tokens[0]);

?>
```

Using the `heredoc` syntax is not needed or recommended here.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, thanks I will use that a lot. Is free-spacing mode specific to PHP or fairly standard?

Comment: @Lea Hayes: Yes, most (PHP, Java, Perl, Python, .NET) have the `'x'` mode - but unfortunately, JavaScript does not.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, got there. It was all in the escape sequences of `$pattern`. Didn't work with HEREDOC or `'this type of literal'` but did work in `"this type of literal"`:

```
$pattern = "/\"(\\\\\"|[^\"])*\"|'(\\\\'|[^'])*'|[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\\-\\d]*|[\\-\\+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?|[=<>!][=]|[?:,()*\\/\\-\\+!]|\\|\\|?|\\&\\&?/";
```

I would be curious to see a working HEREDOC version though as I would prefer to avoid that nasty level of escaping within the pattern itself.